# What's the best compression to use with uploading big catalog by FTP?

Tags: php, ftp, compression, web-hosting

If you are uploading something like Zend Framework using poor internet conneciton it may be problematic.

I think the compression of the catalog is the best solution. But what compression system is the best for this task ? We are using PHP, of course.

I have some ideas like PHP + exec + unrar and http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php but they are all not flexible enough and are not accessible in many hostings.

Comment: Welcome to SO Kamil. What does the catalog contain? What format is it in? Or do you mean uploading the Zend Framework itself?

Comment: Yes, I mean uploading Zend Framework catalog. It takes a lot of time without any compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean uploading the Zend Framework itself (or other programming components) and extracting it on the server side in a shared hosting environment.

This is not easy, as in a shared environment, you can't rely on `unzip` `tar` etc. being available. Any `exec` based idea is therefore not feasible IMO.

Probaby the only reliable possibility is a PHP Unzip class like [**dUnzip**](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2495.html). With that, you would upload the zip file onto the server, and send the script along to unpack it. It requires the `gzip` extension activated in PHP, but that is the case with most providers.

Comment: Thanks, but could you give some links for gzip extension? There are so many extentions and libraries that I'm starting to get confused.

Comment: @Kamil the dunzip class needs this extension enabled: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php you will find info about whether it is enabled or not by using `phpinfo()` on the host.

Answer (score 0):

Iirc, the Zend Framework can be installed via PEAR. You could ask your provider (if you are using shared using which i assume) to install that PEAR package for you and then you should be able to just include it via the php default include-path.

http://code.google.com/p/zend/

Comment: I think the OP is talking about shared hosting environments, where PEAR is usually not available. But if it is, it definitely is the no. 1 choice.

Comment: Karsten, my question is general and ZF is only an example.